# How can I copy a database table to an array while accounting for skipped IDs?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, primary-key, skip

I previously designed the website I'm working on so that I'd just query the database for the information I needed per-page, but after implementing a feature that required every cell from every table on every page (oh boy), I realized for optimization purposes I should combine it into a single large database query and throw each table into an array, thus cutting down on SQL calls.

The problem comes in where I want this array to include skipped IDs (primary key) in the database.  I'll try and avoid having missing rows/IDs of course, but I won't be managing this data and I want the system to be smart enough to account for any problems like this.

My method starts off simple enough:

```
//Run query
$localityResult = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM localities");
$localityMax = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM localities"));
$localityMax = $localityMax[0];

//Assign table to array
for ($i=1;$i<$localityMax+1;$i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($localityResult);
    $localityData["id"][$i] = $row["id"];
    $localityData["name"][$i] = $row["name"];
}

//Output
for ($i=1;$i<$localityMax+1;$i++)
{
    echo $i.". ";
    echo $localityData["id"][$i]." - ";
    echo $localityData["name"][$i];
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

Two notes:

1. Yes, I should probably move that $localityMax check to a PHP loop.
2. I'm intentionally skipping the first array key.

The problem here is that any missed key in the database isn't accounted for, so it ends up outputting like this (sample table):

> 1. 1 - Tok
> 2. 2 - Juneau
> 3. 3 - Anchorage
> 4. 4 - Nashville
> 5. 7 - Chattanooga
> 6. 8 - Memphis
> 7. -
> 8. -

I want to write "Error" or NULL or something when the row isn't found, then continue on without interrupting things.  I've found I can check if $i is less than $row[$i] to see if the row was skipped, but I'm not sure how to correct it at that point.

I can provide more information or a sample database dump if needed.  I've just been stuck on this problem for hours and hours, nothing I've tried is working.  I would really appreciate your assistance, and general feedback if I'm making any terrible mistakes.  Thank you!

---

Edit: I've solved it!  First, iterate through the array to set a NULL value or "Error" message.  Then, in the assignations, set $i to $row["id"] right after the mysql_fetch_assoc() call.  The full code looks like this:

```
//Run query
$localityResult = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM localities");
$localityMax = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM localities"));
$localityMax = $localityMax[0];

//Reset
for ($i=1;$i<$localityMax+1;$i++)
{
    $localityData["id"][$i] = NULL;
    $localityData["name"][$i] = "Error";
}

//Assign table to array
for ($i=1;$i<$localityMax+1;$i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($localityResult);
    $i = $row["id"];
    $localityData["id"][$i] = $row["id"];
    $localityData["name"][$i] = $row["name"];
}

//Output
for ($i=1;$i<$localityMax+1;$i++)
{
    echo $i.". ";
    echo $localityData["id"][$i]." - ";
    echo $localityData["name"][$i];
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

Thanks for the help all!

Comment: For stackoverflow, the correct way to "solve" a question is to select an answer. You could even answer the question yourself and then select your answer as the "correct" answer. This way the question does actually register as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys must be unique in MySQL, so you would get a maximum of one possible blank ID since MySQL would not allow duplicate data to be inserted.

If you were working with a column that is not a primary or unique key, your query would need to be the only thing that would change:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM localities WHERE id != "";
```

or

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM localities WHERE NOT ISNULL(id);
```

EDIT: Created a new answer based on clarification from OP.
If you have a numeric sequence that you want to keep unbroken, and there may be missing rows from the database table, you can use the following (simple) code to give you what you need. Using the same method, your `$i = ...` could actually be set to the first ID in the sequence from the DB if you don't want to start at ID: `1`.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM localities ORDER BY id');

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[(int) $row['id']] = array(
        'id'   => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
    );
}

// This saves a query to the database and a second for loop.
end($data); // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$max = key($data); // fetch the key of the item the internal pointer is set to

for ($i = 1; $i < $max + 1; $i++) {
    if (!isset($data[$i])) {
        $data[$i] = array(
            'id'   => NULL,
            'name' => 'Erorr: Missing',
        );
    }

    echo "$i. {$data[$id]['id']} - {$data[$id]['name']}<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: It's not so much that the id is blank, but that the whole row would be excluded.  For instance: http://i.imgur.com/97Eac.png  I want the array to insert "Error" or NULL when the row is skipped.  I may be misunderstanding you, apologies if so.

Comment: I see, thanks for the updated response.  I ran some benchmarks comparing our code to see which was faster.  I found that at 10,000 reads on my home machine, my code would run in 4.95 seconds, and yours in 3.50 seconds. --

I also converted the code to AdoDB, which runs in 7.5 seconds using my method, 6.2 seconds using yours.  Running it in Adodb Lite (with some slight modifications) runs in 5.5 seconds. --

I converted it to AdoDB to try caching the SQL, but I haven't gotten that part figured out yet.  Just thought I'd share!  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh, there is one big difference though.  The array is $data[index]["name"] in your code, and $data["name"][index] in mine.  Just something to watch out for for any potential googlers out there.

Comment: @SquareWheel Thanks for pointing that out for future seekers. I did that deliberately as it is the typical format for arrays coming back from the database.

Answer (score 0):

After you've gotten your `$localityResult`, you could put all of the id's in an array, then before you `echo $localityDataStuff`, check to see

```
if(in_array($i, $your_locality_id_array)) {
  // do your echoing
} else {
  // echo your not found message
}
```

To make `$your_locality_id_array`:

```
$locality_id_array = array();
foreach($localityResult as $locality) {
  $locality_id_array[] = $locality['id'];
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help!  I rarely go to the internet for help, but this one has been driving me crazy.\n


-oops, enter submits.  Still writing-

Comment: I am not good at commenting...  My Edit:  First of all, thanks for the help!  I rarely go to the internet for help, but this one has been driving me crazy.  I'm receiving "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when testing your code, I'll play with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: No problem, I started using stackoverflow today and it's been immediately helpful, hopefully I can pay it forward. I didn't see that you'd used `$localityResult = mysql_query()`. Your result isn't an array so the foreach loop won't work. You can use the following functon to convert your query to an array, then perform the `foreach` on the returned array.                  `function mysql_evaluate_array($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $values = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($result); ++$i)
        array_push($values, mysql_result($result,$i));
    return $values;
}`